# How important is God in USA politics?

Tags: united-states, political-system, religion

As European citizen (French), I have never been used to seeing biblical notions in politics, but in the USA it seems quite common. For example, former French president Jacques Chirac [revealed](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/andrewbrown/2009/aug/10/religion-george-bush) that the USA invaded Iraq in part for Biblical reasons.

> President Jacques Chirac wanted to know what the hell President Bush
>   had been on about in their last conversation. Bush had then said that
>   when he looked at the Middle East, he saw "Gog and Magog at work" and
>   the biblical prophecies unfolding. But who the hell were Gog and
>   Magog? Neither Chirac nor his office had any idea. But they knew Bush
>   was an evangelical Christian, so they asked the French Federation of
>   Protestants, who in turn asked Professor Römer.

There are more examples like that where God, missions from God, and involvement of God are deeply linked to US political messages. Is God really a strong component of US political life?

Comment: Every time I listened to American political discourse, I was like going back to the middle ages. I speak this as a person who has lived in three continents.

Comment: Considering the phrase "God Bless America!" is almost mandatory for any aspiring politician, I'd say so.

Comment: The first part of this question is answerable, the second part isn't. This needs to be cleaned up. E.g. the reference to Israel is unhelpful and introduces more controversial elements (e.g. how theocratic is Israel? Would you consider it a theocracy or is it just a point of comparison)? I'll post an answer to the question of "What is the importance of God in American politics", but more than that I cannot do.

Comment: FYI, Lord Bertrand Russell totally endorsed Christian love.

Comment: Paradox? Here's another one: Southerner's life style is slow and laid-back, yet the world's fastest shipping giant is governed from the South. Quality cannot be rushed, especially when mishaps are extremely unforgiving.

Comment: The more one studies logic, the less likely he will hold blocs of opinions.

Comment: Nevertheless, the decline of European influence is definitely regrettable. It all began with WWI which, in Bertrand Russell's view, was a civil war through and through. American intellectual level has never got anywhere near the European's.

Comment: Yes, politics in America loves to leverage religion.

Comment: As a pastor, my hope is that God is very important to our politics. :)  As a Baptist, I certainly don't want people claiming God and using that as an excuse to steal power, but as a Christian, I certainly hope God is involved in our politics, because heaven knows we need Him!

Comment: I don't ever recall any biblical reasons stated for the Iraq war.  The reason was that they supposedly had WMDs.

Answer (score 16):

Religion and the idea of God play a large role in American politics, but their influence is limited by the [First Amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution). The relevant text from the First Amendment is as follows:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof

There are two clauses here: the [Establishment Clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Establishment_Clause) and the [Free Exercise Clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Exercise_Clause). The establishment clause prohibits the government from passing laws that explicitly enforce religious law or favor religious institutions. For example, prayer in public schools was ruled unconstitutional because it was a violation of the establishment clause. The free exercise clause prohibits the government from preventing people from practicing their religion.

However, the First Amendment does not prohibit Congress from passing laws due to religious motivations. So long as the laws do not explicitly enforce a solely religious law or institution, and so long as they do not prevent people from practicing their religion, those laws could be constitutional. Congress does pass laws which derive their support from religion.

For example, laws restricting access to abortion derive much of their support from [Christian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_pro-life_movement#Christian_groups), but such laws are not unconstitutional under the First Amendment. Some politicians will also cite religious motivations for their policies. Congressman Paul Broun (R-GA) [explained his voting record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_and_politics_in_the_United_States) as being motivated by his religious beliefs, saying "as your Congressman, I hold the holy Bible as being the major directions to me of how I vote in Washington D.C."

Religion does not just influence American policy, but also American politics in general. For example, [nearly half of Americans](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/religion/story/2012-07-26/athiest-poll-president/56516466/1) would not vote for an Atheist for president, even if the candidate were otherwise well-qualified. Americans would be more comfortable with a well-qualified candidate from any other religious group. Furthermore, a substantial portion of Americans want [politicians to express their faith more often](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/more-americans-want-religion-in-their-politics/), and want religious institutions to be more involved in politics.

It should be noted, however, that the influence of religion in politics is not totally pervasive, but [regionally concentrated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_the_United_States#Statistics). In general, voters from the South will tend to be more religious. If you're interested in the influence and policies of specific religious groups, you can read [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_and_politics_in_the_United_States) on religion and politics in the United States.

Comment: Here's an observation: People in the South are overall affectionate. A leisurely stroll down Memphis streets is a recharging experience because all the friendly greetings one receives. Strangers go out of their ways to say something nice. I used to think it had something to do with religion. Now I think the warm weather and laid-back life style are probably the ultimate cause of their friendliness.

Comment: And good looks too. Good looking people scantily clad. The South is a paradise. What impresses me the most is the total absence of cynicism. Every time you make a mistake, and before you explain it, people have found an excuse for you already.

Comment: +1, but I will note that left-wing ideologies AND new-age spiritualism (see anti-GMO laws) that motivate the opposite side's politicians are in large form NOT in any meaningful way different from Christianity, so singling out Republicans for your example is a bit biased.

Comment: @DVK While I recognize that anti-GMO laws are just as unscientific as some laws Republican politicians endorse, the question was more about organized religion. If somebody asked a question about anti-scientific thought in general, I could definitely include some examples from the political left (though luckily those policies do not appear to have as much a hold on Democratic policy on a national level).

Comment: @Avi - "God" != "organized religion". Especially since the left explicitly insists on that (Wicca treated as just-as-real religion as well as other more weird ones etc...)

Comment: "God", in American politics, typically refers to Jesus' dad. Ie, Christianity. If the question is 'organized religion in general' that'll likely result in different answers.

Comment: @DVK The point still stands. Anti-GMO laws and new-age spiritualism tend to a) have less political impact (for now) and b) not derive their support from belief in a god.

Comment: @Avi - anti-GMO laws forced famine and hunger on a large swaths of human population. New-age spiritualism caused outbreaks of Measles and other dangerous diseases from lack of vaccination. You don't seem to be measuring political impact correctly on that side. They derive their support from belief. Whether you call it a supernatural "god" honestly, or call it "gaia", isn't very relevant to a person's behavior.

Comment: @DVK Those problems are not substantial or too politically influential in the United States, and the US by and large does not have anti-GMO laws. I agree that in places like southeast Asia, it is an extremely important issue. Anti-vaccination hysteria has, unfortunately, had some political influence (in that it has motivated exemption laws), but I do not think that it is motivated by belief in God.

Comment: @DVK anti-GMO laws typically stem from backlash against big-ag and support for local and family farming--not a due to some 'belief' system (though that exists, it's a fringe influence on the laws). The anti-vaccine people are all crazy, but seem to span a full spectrum of religious beliefs, so not isolated to those that do vs. do not believe in God. And as Avi states, while issues, they tend to be localized and not really party-affiliated issues.

Comment: @DA. - I take it you never argued with anti-GMO people. Their main arguments are about "naturalness", etc... (which I wholly fail to deontologically distinguish from "The Good Book says"). And no, starving masses of people are not in my book classified as "localized" issue. I'm willing to be convinced otherwise by statistics but I am pretty sure 90%+ of anti-GMO sentiment is on "D" side of US political binary

Comment: @DVK I live in a state that hotly debates it every election. There are definitely the hippy arguments, but the vast majority of the arguments stem from local farming groups and associations. The bigger backlash against GMOs isn't the genetics, but against the MONSANTO patent lawyers suing local farmers out of business.

Comment: (and as a complete aside, GMO patents have little to do with feeding the planet and much more to do with monopolizing food--but that's a fun debate for another time...)

Comment: @DVK - You seem to be taking the viewpoint that the question asks "How important is personal belief in USA politics?"  It doesn't.  It's asking *specifically* about capital-G God.  As in [Christianity.SE].  While I'll certainly agree that a fanatic born-again Christian and a fanatic new-age spiritualist may share certain traits, and will *certainly* let their beliefs color their political decisions, **the OP did not ask about the latter.**

Comment: @Bobson - as I said, deontologically, they are identical. Both based on faith-based belief in unprovable.

Comment: @DVK while I agree that that makes the nameless equally wrong and equally useless, OP was only asking about one such belief in the question

Comment: @DVK I have no idea how the left-wing hippy dippy anti-GMO lobby is derivable from a question about capital-G monotheistic divinity _in manner the question has been asked_. Ask your question directly; as re-framing this one isn't working for you.

Comment: @LateralFractal - The fact that OP is likely completely ignorant of the fact that there is a possibility of religious belief NOT involving monotheistic "G"od is not grounds for succumbing to the same bias in the answer. As it is, the Q+A validates - while looking very fact-based - a **completely untrue** view that only Christians have outsized influence on USA politics due to faith based belief, where nothing can be further from the truth.

Comment: @DVK Then it's another one of those questions that presumes their desired answer. But you know - you can still answer the question by posting an answer along the lines of _"No, it isn't any more politically influential or important than other non-Christian emotive stances."_ Blaming the questioner gets us precisely nowhere when you can still answer. Unless _asking_ was the crime? This isn't a hard science stack. I've come to accept that a while back.

Comment: @LateralFractal - if you pay attention, that is **100% precisely what I did**. I very politely pointed out the possible bias to the answerer, gave them an example to use to avoid said bias, and upvoted the answer anyway. Then everyone else who doesn't seem to be bothered by biases in posts unless they are anti-progressive started arguing with me that my comment was inapplicable because the question as asked (in biased way) put my comment outside the scope.

Comment: @DVK Hmm. It it seems you wanted Avi to add your outlook to their answer. I'm not entirely sure that's best approach. Shouldn't the question have been commented on instead of an answer if the question is the root source of the bias?

Comment: @LateralFractal - I wanted to avoid an answer that validates a completey biased view, but thanks to how the question was phrased, looks 100% objective and non-biased due to its overall high quality. And because of the latter, adding my own answer to balance the bias is 100% out of the question, I have not much of actual substance to add to Avi's analysis

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18072/discussion-on-answer-by-avi-how-important-is-god-in-usa-politics).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately God is often very "important" in US politics, although it should not be. I don't mean that religion is worse than government, and in fact, in the past, there was often little distinction between the two. However, the political and legal systems within the United States are founded on the constitution. That is what gives validity to those systems.

But it is quite often seen that politicians who are religious will often try to convince people that God trumps the constitution and so the constitution can be ignored in such instances. We see this with same sex marriage, with warfare, etc.

Let's start with the constitution itself. What is it? It is a contract between the people and the government, giving said government certain powers and responsibilities. That is why it determines the validity of the political and legal system.

In regard to same sex marriage. The 14th amendment requires that a law treat all citizens alike, and yet, there are many, who due to religious persuasion, wish to prevent same sex couples from obtaining marriage licenses.

Moving on to warfare, religion has and continues to be a major player in the excuse to wage war. Bush often invoked god when justifying his decision to go to war. We can see an example of this in the quote "God told me to end the tyranny in Iraq" (http://www.theguardian.com/world/2005/oct/07/iraq.usa)

Adding another example as supporting evidence, we have the push to teach creationism in biology class. While creationism should be welcome in philosophical discussions in school, it is not scientific and therefore should not be in a science class.

Of course, a discussion on how religion influences politics in America would be want without mentioning Islam. It is an unfortunate reality that there is a group of Islamist extremists who mean us harm. Of course, part of that problem arose from secular mistakes, such as [funding what would become our main enemies in the middle east during the cold war](http://newsone.com/1205745/cia-osama-bin-laden-al-qaeda/)!.

Lastly there is the counter-religious movement which hopes to remove all religious expression from public spaces. This is often justified by the idea of separation of church and state: [a phrase which does not exist in the constitution](http://www.forbes.com/sites/billflax/2011/07/09/the-true-meaning-of-separation-of-church-and-state/)!. The constitution discusses the free expression of religion. Therefore the argument of whether or not we can express religion in public venues is a large part of political discourse in America today.

Comment: This post has no fact content. Please seek to answer the question using things other than your opinion

Comment: Is the edit more satisfactory?